# ZEND FORM radiobox with input

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have this zend form element :

$form->getElement('my_element')->addMultiOptions(array('option1' => 'option1', 'option2' => 'option2', 'option3' => 'option3', 'option4' => 'option4'));

So I get :

( ) option 1

( ) option 2

( ) option 3

( ) option 4

Now let's say I want to add a input (type = text) right after option 3 .. so something like this :

( ) option 1

( ) option 2

( ) option 3 [input]

( ) option 4

Is this possible? I'm kinde lost here

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible, but you'll need to [create your own element](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html) and add this functionality.

But if you don't know very much the framework, I sugest you to use view scripts and build your form manually.

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414137/how-can-i-easily-add-a-link-to-a-form-in-zend-framework/3415541#3415541

[Recommended Path For Zend Form Element View Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202633/recommended-path-for-zend-form-element-view-scripts/2206287#2206287)

http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/model-view-controller-mvc-21/zend-forms-w-view-script-1061.html

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, check here for the quick solution http://paveldubinin.com/2011/04/zend-form-radio-buttons/ using custom element.